# Classification of singularities of a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, residue-calculus, laurent-series, singularity

I'm trying to classify in $\mathbb C\cup\{\infty\}$, the singularities of the function
$$f(z)=\frac{e^{z^2}\sin(1/z)}{z}.$$
Clearly the function has only one singularity in $z=0$ and in order to tudy its nature I have tried to find the Laurent expansion of the function at $z=0$.
$$f(z)=\dfrac{1}{z}\cdot e^{z^2}\cdot\sin(1/z)=\dfrac{1}{z}\cdot\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m!}z^{2m}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-)^n}{(2n+1)!}(1/z)^{2n+1}=\\
1/z\cdot\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\left(\sum_{m,n\ge 0,2m-(2n-1)=k}\frac{(-)^n}{m!(2n+1)!} \right)z^k$$
and from this point I don't know how to substitute the index $n$ in function of $k$ and $m$ because I'd obtain a rational expression...

Answer (score 1):

First hint: since $g(z)=e^{z^2}$ is entire and never vanishes, the singularity of $f$ at $0$ has the same type as
$$
f_1(z)=\dfrac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{1}{z}\sin\frac{1}{z}
$$
that you should be able to classify.

Second hint: the function has also a singularity at $\infty$.

Comment: Ok, we have $$\frac{1}{z}\cdot \sum_0^{\infty} \frac{(-)^n}{(2n+1)!}z^{-(2n+1)}$$ hence it is an essential singularity since $|\{n\in\mathbb Z:n<0,a_n\ne 0\}|=\infty$.

Comment: @Alchemist That's right.

Comment: sorry for the previous mistake... it was terrible

Comment: @Alchemist `:-D` What about the singularity at $\infty$? You *can't* remove $e^{z^2}$.

Comment: I think I should study $e^{1/z^2}\sin(z)z$.

Comment: @Alchemist That's correct. Now $z\sin z$ is $z^2h(z)$ where $h(0)\ne0$ and $h$ doesn't vanish in a neighborhood of $0$, so…

Comment: I'd look at the set of negative powers of Laurent expansion of $f(1/z)$